# Sql join 1 row with sum of multiple rows

Tags: postgresql

1st table:

```
A               id    
       1        200
2366.533        200
3408.467        200
```

2nd table:

```
    C   D       E       F   id  
    XRP 5515    5776    0   200
```

My query:

```
select * from table1 
join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

I have the following output after running my code using a classic JOIN statement between two tables:

```
A               C   D       E       F 
       1        XRP 5515    5776    0
2366.533        XRP 5515    5776    0
3408.467        XRP 5515    5776    0
```

The first column is from Table1 and the following 4 columns from table 2.
As you can see the columns on the right are the same. Simply because there was actually only 1 raw which has been duplicated during the JOIN.

I would like to sum column A when I join and keep only 1 row from Table2 with the following output in this case.

```
      A         C   D       E       F 
      5776      XRP 5515    5776    0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would join to a distinct subquery on the second table:

```
select t1.A, t2.C, t2.D, t2.E, t2.F
from table1 t1
inner join (select distinct C, D, E, F from table2) t2
    on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the 2nd table. It is actually already 1 row. So there is no need of a distinct statement?

Comment: @delalma Well if you expect each `id` in the second table would always have only one record, your current query should already suffice.  That being said, there would be nothing _wrong_ with using my answer, just that it would not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could figure out an answer:

```
select t2.C, t2.D, t2.E, t2.F, sum(t1) 
from (
  select * from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
  ) sub
group by 1,2,3,4
```